# APACHE NIFI lookup workaround

Tags: apache-nifi, lookup

End goal:
Be able to identify a flow file as an insert or update

Idea:
Bring in record from source,
compare the PK in the flowfile to that sheet,file,tbd of a query from the target DB that pulls all pk's for that view. Then I can route that file as an insert or update. This is for speed purposes.

Question for Stack:
Is there a way I could compare the PK of my current flowfile to that of a flowfile of all values generated(I'd only generate this flowfile like every 6,12,18, or 24 hours)

Comment: Been thinking of a way to determine inserts/updates,
I think we would need a daily HDFS job that runs a query against each view 
Select PK from targerDB.VIEW_NAME

We then house these values in HDFS

We use the SCANATTRIBUTE processor which does a lookup on a “DICTIONARY FILE” 
Route Matched to Update flow 
Route Unmatched to Insert flow

Comment: Would LookupRecord/LookupAttribute with a SimpleDatabaseLookupService / DatabaseRecordLookupService work for your use case?

Comment: @mattyb with the lookuprecord, I want to check on the primary key "service_id" which is the attribute $.service_id, in my table auth_service_tb in the database AUTH5P1 schema SVC5P1, so I'm not seeing how I'll be able to configure it to check the specific table in the specific schema to search for a matching value. 

Can you please help?

Comment: LookupRecord is meant to use a field from each record, not an attribute. You could use UpdateRecord upstream to add your attribute as a field to each record, then do a lookup using that (and a routing strategy of `matched` or `unmatched`). Each record in a flowfile going to `matched` means the ID already exists, and the opposite is true for the `unmatched` relationship.